# How can I see the branch history of a directory in P4V?

Tags: p4v

In P4V I can select a file, view its history, and use the options under the "show branch history" button to see changes made in other branches.

When I select a directory however, the "show branch history" button disappears. How do I view the history over different branches of *all* the files contained under a directory?

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest to use Revision Graph to do this. It'll let you follow the path of all of a folder's files back into other branches (can also do it recursively if there are subfolders).

Be warned: the output can get intense if there's a lot of other branches, and/or a lot of files. There's a filter on it so you can narrow down which files you care to look at though.